# MS Access change textbox value from module

Tags: variables, ms-access, vbscript, textbox

I want to change the value of a text box on in a report according to the input box value from within module.

```
Public Sub ChangeTextBox()
Dim UserText As String

UserText = InputBox("Enter The Value")
'The part I don't understand is how to branch out to the text box name
'I know you have to do something like Form!Formname.textbox name but I'm so confused
'How do I link it to the textbox from within module?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below code .

formname is the form name
txtName is textbox name

```
Public Sub ChangeTextBox()
    Dim UserText As String


    UserText = InputBox("Enter The Value")

    If UserText <> "" Then
        ActiveCell.Value = s
        formname.txtName = "dfd" ' where txtName is textbox name
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

**Object Brower View**
[image]

[image]

Comment: I get Variable not defined on the formname, I'm not using "formname" I'm typing in the actual form which is "PrintLabel".

Comment: @like-a-trainee i hope the image helped you to sort out the issue.

Comment: Yeah I understand the image but I'm still getting "Variable not defined" error. It debug is seeing it as variable not a table reference... :/

Comment: Should I be doing something like this? 

               
Forms![PrintLabel]![textboxname].Text = ""

Comment: @like-a-trainee On which line you get this error. Can you put the code in OP.

Comment: sorry It's long code, but I guess what I'm trying to say is I'm having trouble referencing to a textbox located inside a form. I tried this
Forms!PrintLabels!bagnumber.Text = i
Forms!PrintLabels!bagtotal.Text = numberOfCopies

Comment: I got your point. Like i showed in the image type the name of form as it appears in Coding envoirnment then when you put a dot(period) . you will get all the property. The textbox now becomes the property of the form and you can accordingly set its value.